# Can't run codes while using the terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, compiler-errors

I'm using VSCodium

After running this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int e;

    cout << "pick a number";
    
    cin >> e;

    cout << "2 * e";
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the output page, it prints "pick a number", but I wasn't able to write anything, so I changed it to "Run In Terminal" in Code Runner extension, and after running it, I get this error:

```
PS C:\\Users\\M lapan\> cd "C:\\Users\\MLAPAN\~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp" ; if ($?) { g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile } ; if ($?) { .\\tempCodeRunnerFile }
cd : An object at the specified path C:\\Users\\MLAPAN\~1 does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

+ cd "C:\\Users\\MLAPAN\~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp" ; if ($?) { g++ tempCodeRu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
  
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I searched the error on YouTube and Google, but couldn't find anyone with the same issue as mine. I tried deleting everything in `settings.js`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Sounds like you are struggling with an IDE. You should add which one you are using to the question. *Code Runner extension* suggests it's Visual Studio Code, but confirmation would be a good thing.

Comment: Note: `cout << "2 * e";` emits the string `2 * e`. It does not multiply e by 2. That would require you to remove the quotes: `cout << 2 * e;`. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/3Wb8de3c7

Comment: I wonder if the space in C:\\Users\\M lapan\ is causing the runner extension (and by extension the underlying toolchain) to have a fit.

Comment: Code Runner can refuse to work at some weird paths, it seems. Why does it try to use that directory? Did you save your source file there?

Comment: That path looks really odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It by changing the path of the file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).